# I have a Firestore database and in my Flutter app i retrieved the docID i need. How do i retrieve a specific field of the document usign docID?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I found the document id of the document i need. each of my documents in the database 'maindb' has 4 fields(caretaker,elderly,pulse,temp). If my userID is available, what is the syntax to retrieve just the integer value in the pulse field?

Comment: What have you already attempted? I believe this common scenario will be listed in their documentation.

Comment: I extensively searched their documentation and stack overflow but I could not find anything

Comment: It's been a while since I last worked with Firestore, but I'll post what I think is the solution below. Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took this straight from Flutter Fire [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#document--query-snapshots). I'm not sure if you're using that to connect to firestore, but at least it should be a good starting point.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(userId) <--- Just use the document ID here
    .get()
    .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        print('Document exists on the database');
      }
    });
```

This will return the entire document related to that userId. Then you can just take whatever entry you need from it.

Comment: Oh thank you so much! This is exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked. If you can, accept the answer and help other people find it.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. You cannot retrieve single fields in documents. The entire document is retrieved, and then you can slice the information you want.

You can however, search and query documents, based on a single or multiple field.

i.e `where('pulse', isEqualTo: 75)`.

Regarding billing, it's the same thing, Firestore is billed based on document reads\writes. So writing a single field or writing an entire document, is the same price, so no worries.

Comment: Hi thank you, but what is the syntax for retrieving a document using docID ? Here is how I found docid.
main.where('elderly', isEqualTo: elderly).get().then(
        (QuerySnapshot snapshot) => {
          snapshot.docs.forEach((f) {
            docid = f.reference.id;
          }),
        },
      );